# How to configure the dictionary in OS X to translate Spanish and Hebrew?

Tags: macos, dictionary

As you all probably know when using multi-touch pad with three fingers and clicking on a word in English you get the definition from the dictionary.

Are there any other possible languages such as Spanish and Hebrew?